# How to get download size in Poco::HTTPClientSession?

Tags: c++, download, poco, windows-networking

```
HTTPClientSession session(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort());
HTTPRequest req(HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET, path, HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
session.setTimeout(Poco::Timespan(20,0));
session.sendRequest(req);
HTTPResponse res;
istream& rs = session.receiveResponse(res);

File saveTo(request.name,File::WriteOnly,true);
char aux_buffer[1024];
rs.read(aux_buffer, 1024);
std::streamsize n = rs.gcount();
while (n > 0){
    saveTo.write(aux_buffer,n);
    if (rs){
        rs.read(aux_buffer, 1024);
        n = rs.gcount();
    }
    else n = 0;
    }
```

}

How to get download size before i download it? 
Because sometimes i get corrupted file, so i want to check the size.

Comment: Are you receiving binary or textual data? Is the file opened in binary mode or textual mode by default?

Comment: PDF file, so i think download in binary

Comment: Then you need to make sure you open the file in binary mode, otherwise writing to the file may convert the byte `0x0a` (newline) to the byte sequence `0x0d 0x0a` (carriage-return and newline).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`HTTPResponse::getContentLength()`](http://pocoproject.org/docs-1.5.0/Poco.Net.HTTPMessage.html#18624) or `getContentLength64()`:

> Returns the content length for this message, which may be UNKNOWN_CONTENT_LENGTH if no Content-Length header is present.

Note, that you have to call `HTTPClientSession::receiveResponse()` first to receive the headers. You may also want to check `HTTPResponse::getStatus()` to verify that the request was ok and `HTTPResponse::getContentType()` if you're expecting a specific type.

For PDFs you can check the begin/end markers of the file itself. A proper PDF file should begin with `%PDF-X.Y%` (where X.Y represents the version) and end with `%%EOF` possibly followed by a 0x0D and/or 0x0A. A PDF file may contain multiple `%%EOF` markers.